# Batch file findstr with spaces and blank lines

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script below which reads strings with spaces, line by line from a reference text file(testException.txt). I am using findstr to search in my text.txt to find any match to the strings in the reference file. If there is any match, i want to output everything in the text.txt to an error textfile and exit the loop.

```
:find.bat
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


set source=testException.txt
set location=text.txt


for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%L IN (!source!) DO (

@findstr /B /I /C:"%%L" "!location!"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (type !location! >> Error.txt goto:eof) else (call)
)
pause
```

When I execute my script, it outputs as many times as the number of patterns in my testException.txt. It seems like my goto:eof does not end my for loop. Below is my text.txt and testException.txt. Any help & suggestions for a better way is greatly appreciated.

***text.txt***

hello, how are u.

im fine ty.

lol. apple 123 is here

***testException.txt***

orange 321

apple 123

lol 423

Comment: Add an ampersand between `>> Error.txt` and `goto :eof`

Comment: Can you use `findstr /b /i /l /g:"!source!" "!location!"` instead of the loop?

Comment: Thanks Happy Face. Adding & did it for me.